# Static lifetime annotation of a Pyo3-bound object

Tags: python, rust, rust-tokio, pyo3

I'm trying to create a client using Rust and its Tokio runtime, and bind it to python using `pyo3` and `pyo3-asyncio`. To bring this into a minimal example, let's say I want to have a `Client` class that connects to `127.0.0.1:1234` and has an `echo` method that processes data incoming over the socket.  I want the function to return a Python coroutine so I can use it alongside `async` functions in my Python codebase. Example usecase:

```py
import asyncio
from client import Client  # pyo3-bound rust code

c = Client()
asyncio.run(c.echo())
```

I have followed the docs of `pyo3-asyncio` and found [this function](https://docs.rs/pyo3-asyncio/0.13.2/pyo3_asyncio/tokio/fn.into_coroutine.html). I wrote this (hopefully minimal) snippet to reproduce the issue:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;


#[pyclass]
struct Client {
    rt: Runtime,
    stream: TcpStream,
}

#[pymethods]
impl Client {
    #[new]
    fn new() -> PyResult<Self> {
        let rt = Runtime::new().expect("Error creating runtime");
        let stream = rt.block_on(async {
            TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:1234").await
        })?;
        Ok(Self { rt, stream })
    }

    fn echo(&mut self) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
        let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
        let py = gil.python();
        pyo3_asyncio::tokio::into_coroutine(py, async move {
            loop {
                let mut vec = Vec::new();
                self.stream.read(&mut vec);
                println!("{:?}", vec);
            }
        })
    }
}


#[pymodule]
fn client(py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    let runtime = Runtime::new().expect("Tokio runtime error");
    m.add_class::<Client>()?;
    pyo3_asyncio::tokio::init(runtime);

    Ok(())
}
```

The problem seems to be that `self`, that is `Client`, has an anonymous lifetime but it is expected to have a `'static` one. The compiler says:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> src/lib.rs:28:60
   |
25 |       fn call_every_second(&mut self, callback: PyObject) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
   |                            --------- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
...
28 |           pyo3_asyncio::tokio::into_coroutine(py, async move {
   |  ____________________________________________________________^
29 | |             loop {
30 | |                 let mut vec = Vec::new();
31 | |                 self.stream.read(&mut vec);
32 | |                 println!("{:?}", vec);
33 | |             }
34 | |         })
   | |_________^ ...is captured here...
   |
```

Is there a way I can ensure a static lifetime of the client? Perhaps I'm approaching the problem incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

The `into_coroutine()` function requires a `'static` future, so you can't borrow `Client`'s `stream` field inside the future. A workaround is to change `Client` so it stores `stream` as `Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>`:

```rust
struct Client {
    rt: Runtime,
    stream: Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>, // using tokio::sync::Mutex
}
```

You can then give `into_coroutine()` access to the stream through the `Arc`:

```rust
    // ...
    let stream = Arc::clone(&self.stream);
    pyo3_asyncio::tokio::into_coroutine(py, async move {
        loop {
            let mut vec = Vec::new();
            stream.lock().await.read(&mut vec).await?;
            println!("{:?}", vec);
        }
    })
}
```